# Possible to print the IPDB/Celery-RDB stack trace ('where') to stdout from within the code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, debugging, celery, ipdb

Inputting 'w(here)' into the IPDB or RDB will print out a stack trace.

Is there a way to do this without entering `set_trace()`?

I guess what I'm imagining would be something like `print(w)`, or otherwise simply printing the stacktrace at the point where I `set_trace()`.

Comment: you mean `traceback.print_stack`?

Comment: @georgexsh how is this used? do you mean `traceback.print_exc`?

Comment: @georgexsh yes, exactly what I was looking for. Thanks. Will accept answer if you post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`traceback.print_stack()` is what you want, it will print current call stack start from `sys._getframe()`, see more on [its doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/traceback.html#traceback.print_stack).